# Duda envio respuesta con ajax

Tags: ajax

Ayudenme a entender como funciona esto por favor. ¿Cómo se recibe en .outer_div el mensaje que se crea en editar_banner.php a través de data por petición ajax? Veo que tiene esto:

```
$(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Pero no entiendo que es lo que va en el data. ¿Es lo enviado en el el mismo ajax o es la respuesta que se crea en editar_banner.php?

Este seria el script de ajax. Entiendan que hay un div con clase .outer_div donde se recibe esto.

```
<script>
    $("#editar_banner").submit(function(e) {

          $.ajax({
              url: "ajax/editar_banner.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: $("#editar_banner").serialize(),
               beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#loader").html("Cargando...");
              },
              success:function(data){
                    $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#loader").html("");
                }
        });
         e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

por otra parte tengo el editar_banner.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST["titulo"])){
/* Llamar la Cadena de Conexion*/
include ("../../conexion.php");
// escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
 $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST['titulo'], ENT_QUOTES)));
 $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['descripcion']));
 $descripcion_corta = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['descripcion_corta']));
 $url_web = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['url_web']));
 $orden = intval($_POST['orden']);
 $estado = intval($_POST['estado']);
 $id_banner=intval($_POST['id_banner']);
 $sql="UPDATE portafolio SET titulo='$titulo', descripcion='$descripcion', orden='$orden', estado='$estado', descripcion_corta='$descripcion_corta', url_web='$url_web' WHERE id='$id_banner'";
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// if user has been added successfully
if ($query) {
    $messages[] = "Datos  han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente.";
} else {
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
}

if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong>
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    if (isset($messages)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                <?php
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                            echo $message;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

}

Comment: Obtienes alguna respuesta? Tienes un error o no entiendes el codigo?

Comment: El codigo funciona bien. Simplemente no entiendo como se genera la respuesta en $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow'); ¿es que simplemente se sustituye data por el contenido de editar_banner.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que tu pregunta se refiere a que es lo que recibes en la variable *data* en este fragmento:

```
$(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Responderé eso.

Como verás estas haciendo una consulta ajax en la cual envías datos al servidor, estos datos lo haz especificado aquí:

```
data: $("#editar_banner").serialize()
```

Eso es lo que envías al servidor, en el servidor recibes y trabajas con eso que haz enviado, si todo en el servidor va bien estas construyendo una alerta con este codigo:

```
if (isset($messages)){
 ?> 
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> 
<strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong> 
<?php 
foreach ($messages as $message) {
 echo $message; 
} ?>
</div>
```

Bien pues te explico, las consultas ajax envían datos al servidor y son capaces de recibir una respuesta de este por eso tenemos el método success del ajax. En tu código estas  recibiendo el mensaje que has construido en el servidor y lo estas mostrando en div con este codigo:

```
success:function(data){ //recibiendo la alerta que se construyo en el servidor
 $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');// Agregando al div la alerta que se construyo en el servidor
 $("#loader").html("");//vaciando el elemento loader
 }
```

Y como ves así funciona ajax te permite enviar y recibir datos del servidor de esa manera.

Comment: Entonces, yo estaba en lo cierto cuando decía que data en .html(data) es lo mismo que sustituirlo por "editar_banner.php" ¿no es asi?. Es que estoy preguntando esto porque este "editar_banner.php" no tiene un return o algo que diga esto es la respuesta. Simplemente se procesa este fichero y todo lo que salga aparece en data. En este caso es un mensaje pero podrían haber varios o incluso funciones. No se si me estoy pasando con esto ultimo. 
Por favor, dime que opinas. Tú pareces conocer bien este tema.

Comment: No seria exactamente lo mismo que el contenido del php sino que dentro del lenguaje php estas construyendo elementos de html que esos son lo que se regresan y muestran.

Comment: Es decir no puedes sustituir lo que recibes por el archivo de php entero ya que php es capaz de construir html dinámicamente y ese html que se construye es tu respuesta.

Comment: Además php es un lenguaje de programación mientras html es un lenguje de hipertexto marcado como si fuera un constructor de elementos visuales por lo que no se pueden sustituir php como lenguaje de programación puede manejar datos que es lo que haces con tu código.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: $("#editar_banner").serialize()
```

No es más que el contenido del formulario que lo estás serializando y enviandoselo a **editar_banner.php**

Comment: Sí, eso lo entiendo. Lo que no entiendo es como se genera en $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow'); el resultado de editar_banner. php. ¿Acaso data aquí es lo mismo que sustuir editar_banner.php?

Comment: antes que todo, quiero preguntarte algo, el código te funciona??? o simplemente quieres conocer el funcionamiento del mismo??? ** **outer_div** es una clase que está en un objeto html que estás ocultando si el envio de formulario es satisfactorio

Comment: Sí, el código funciona perfectamente. Y como dices quiero entender como funciona. Ahora si lees mi anterior comentario verás que lo que no comprendo es que es lo que se recibe en data en $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow'); ¿es el resultado de editar_banner. php? ¿Acaso data aquí es lo mismo que sustuir editar_banner.php?

Comment: outer_div es una clase que utilizan en algún lugar de tu codigo HTML. LO que haces es que cuando envias el formulario y esto lo haces de manera satisfactoria, ocultas el contenida de esa classe

Comment: Pero yo ya sé que es outer_div. No estoy preguntando eso. Estoy preguntando de donde viene el data en la parte .html(data) ¿Sería como sustituir data por editar_banner.php?
No sé como puedo explicarlo más claro.